# Index matching with multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas dataframe with different size. two dataframe looks like

```
df1 = 

x   y   data
1   2   5
2   2   7
5   3   9
3   5   2
```

and another dataframe looks like:

df2 =

```
x   y   value
5   3   7
1   2   4
3   5   2
7   1   4
4   6   5
2   2   1
7   5   8
```

I am trying to merge these two dataframe so that the final dataframe expected to have same combination of x and y with respective value. I am expecting final dataframe in this format:

```
x   y   data    value
1   2   5      4
2   2   7      1
5   3   9      7
3   5   2      2
```

I tride this code but not getting expected results.

```
dfB.set_index('x').loc[dfA.x].reset_index()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), by default `how='inner'` so it can be omit and if join only on same columns parameter `on` can be omit too:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2))
   x  y  data  value
0  1  2     5      4
1  2  2     7      1
2  5  3     9      7
3  3  5     2      2
```

If in real data are multiple same column names use:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['x','y']))

   x  y  data  value
0  1  2     5      4
1  2  2     7      1
2  5  3     9      7
3  3  5     2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.merge(df2,by='x')
```

This will do